# How to fix '$' was used before it was defined in both jslint and jshint using coding?

Tags: jquery, jslint, jshint

I am using **jQUery** . And in **jslint**, I keep on

```
'$' was used before it was defined.
```

or

```
document was used before it was defined.
```

I know I can stop those from showing up by using

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/
```

But I wanted to actually **fix this through coding** if possible. So, I did like before.

```
var $, document;
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
```

However, now it says

```
Two warnings
1   Redefinition of '$'.
1   Redefinition of 'document'.
```

in **jshint**. Is there a coding that I can use to please **both jshint and jslint**?

Comment: I don't think there's any way for jslint to know that the variable is being defined by an external library. That's what the comment is for, to tell it things that you know that it doesn't.

Comment: The question is - is the code correct? If it is not, you should change it. If it is correct, you have nothing to fix, so adding proper comments is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use jslint comments. The following suggestion uses a few tricks. Having tricks in your code won't help for maintainability. Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/t8e8Lvzp/1/):

```
var myApplication = function () {
    "use strict";
    var $ = this.$, document = this.document, console = this.console;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //...
        console.log("test");
    });
};

myApplication.call(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, and don't have to, fix it by coding. `$` does in fact exist as global variable in a different file. That's exactly what `/*global ... */` is for.